# Systemd logging to journal stops after service outputs very long lines

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I have a process that outputs its logs to standard error, and I'm running it as a systemd service with `Type=simple`. I have left the `StandardError` and `StandardOutput` fields at their default values (`inherit` and `journal`) and have set the `SyslogIdentifier` field - so I expect to see the logs from the service in journal with the specified identifier.

All this works quite well most of the time. The problem starts when the service starts outputting very long lines to text - over 50KB.

It appears that systemd (or journal) are breaking long log lines (I'm not sure but from testing I believe the limit is 48KB) to appear on multiple journal messages. But after my service has been running for a while (a few hours at least) outputting very large lines, suddenly the logs in the journal stops. I can see the service is still running properly, and I believe it is still outputting log messages (though I can't see any errors that it may or may not try to show), but no more logs are sent to the journal.

I tried to reproduce this behavior with dumb shell scripts that output very large text blocks (basically `dd`ing some `/dev/urandom` through `base64 -w0`) and I cannot reproduce this behavior with simple tests.

I would appreciate any ideas about what may be the problem and what other tests I can run.

Comment: For info, the max length of log lines is set by `LineMax=`, see [man journald.conf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/journald.conf.5.html).